# CAML have You know any tutorial?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Are You know any tutorial of CAML ? How buld efficient query to lists items ?

Comment: Due to broad nature of Q made Community Wiki (thx Rob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Writing CAML Queries For Retrieving List Items from a SharePoint List](http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/writing-caml-queries-for-retrieving-list-items-from-a-sharepoint-list)